# Nested Anova in python with Spm1d. Can't print f statistics and p values

Tags: python, statistics, anova, matlab-spm

I'm looking for a simple solution to perform multi-factor ANOVA analysis in python. A 2-factor nested ANOVA is what I'm after, and the SPM1D python module is one way to do that, however I am having an issue.

http://www.spm1d.org/doc/Stats1D/anova.html#two-way-nested-anova

for any of the nested approach examples, there is never any F-statistic or p_values printed, nor can I find any way to print them or send them to a variable.

To go through the motions of running one of their examples, where B is nested inside A, with Y observations:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot
import spm1d

dataset      = spm1d.data.uv1d.anova2nested.SPM1D_ANOVA2NESTED_3x3()
Y,A,B        = dataset.get_data()

#(1) Conduct ANOVA:
alpha        = 0.05
FF           = spm1d.stats.anova2nested(Y, A, B, equal_var=True)
FFi          = FF.inference(0.05)
print( FFi )

#(2) Plot results:
pyplot.close('all')
FFi.plot(plot_threshold_label=True, plot_p_values=True)
pyplot.show()
```

The only indication of statistical significance provided is whether the h0 hypothesis is rejected or not.

```
> print( FFi )

SPM{F} inference list
   design    :  ANOVA2nested
   nEffects  :  2
Effects:
   A     z=(1x101) array      df=(2, 6)    h0reject=True
   B     z=(1x101) array      df=(6, 36)   h0reject=False
```

In reality, that should be enough. However, in science, scientists like to think of something as more or less significant, which is actually kind of crap... significance is binary. But that's how they think about it, so I have to play along in order to get work published.

The example code produces a matplotlib plot, and this **DOES** have the f statistic and p_values on it!

```
#(2) Plot results:
pyplot.close('all')
FFi.plot(plot_threshold_label=True, plot_p_values=True)
pyplot.show()
```

[image: \spm1d\examples\stats1d\ex_anova2nest.py]
But I can't seem to get any output which prints it.

```
FFi.get_p_values
```

and

```
FFi.get_f_values
```

produce the output:

```
<bound method SPMFiList.get_p_values <kabammi edit -- or get_f_values> of SPM{F} inference list
   design    :  ANOVA2nested
   nEffects  :  2
Effects:
   A     z=(1x101) array      df=(2, 6)    h0reject=True
   B     z=(1x101) array      df=(6, 36)   h0reject=False
```

So I don't know what to do. Clearly the FFi.plot class can access the p_values (with plot_p_values) but FFi.get_p_values cant!!? Can anyone lend a hand?

cheers,
K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get the p values is to use the `get_p_values` method that you mention, you just need to call the method by adding `()` to the end.

```
p = FFi.get_p_values()
print(p)
```

This yields:

```
([0.016584151119287904], [])
```

To see more detailed information for each effect in 2+-way ANOVA, including p values, use `print` along with the individual F statistics like this:

```
print( FFi[0] )
print( FFi[1] )
```

The first print statement will produce output like this:

```
SPM{F} inference field
   SPM.effect    :   Main A
   SPM.z         :  (1x101) raw test stat field
   SPM.df        :  (2, 6)
   SPM.fwhm      :  11.79254
   SPM.resels    :  (1, 8.47993)
Inference:
   SPM.alpha     :  0.050
   SPM.zstar     :  24.30619
   SPM.h0reject  :  True
   SPM.p_set     :  0.017
   SPM.p_cluster :  (0.017)
```

You can retrieve the clusters' p values like this:

```
p = [F.p  for  F in FFi]
```

which gives the same result as calling `get_p_values`.

Note that there are no p values in this case for `FFi[1]` because the test statistic fails to cross the `alpha`-defined threshold (see the "Main B" panel in the figure above).  If you need to report p values in this case as well, one option is simply to use "p > alpha".  More precise p value are available parametrically up until about p = 0.5, but larger p values than that are not very accurate using parametric methods, so if you need p values for all cases consider using the nonparametric version:  `spm1d.stats.nonparam.anova2nested`.

Comment: Ahh, it's a function, not a property. Silly me. Fantastic. Thanks Todd. So FFi[0] is group A, with the nested values B being FFi[1].. and so on.

Comment: Yes, you can also access the individual effects like a dictionary:  ```FFi['A']``` and ```FFi['B']```.  Also ```FFi['AB']``` if there is an interaction term.